# Can't Get RSS to work (Empty_feed)

Tags: rss

I've tried adding `dynamic="no"`.. removing curly brackets.. adding `status="publish"` since that's the status that a blog post has to be to display.. all no luck so far.  Here's the rss file

**code removed due to update**

I'm using structure, so that would explain the `{page_url}`

**Update**

My blogs channel is "blog" but i switched the channel to "personal_trainer_directory" just to see if other channels would work, and it did.. So what could be causing the issue with this now?

Current code:

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

        <channel>

        <title><![CDATA[Blog]]></title>
        <link>{channel_url}</link>
        <description>{channel_description}</description>
        <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
        <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
        <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
        <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
        <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="10" dynamic_start="no" disable="member_data|pagination"}
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[{title}]]></title>
            <link>{page_url}</link>
            <guid>{page_url}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[{article_body}]]></description>
            <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}]]></dc:subject>
            <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
        </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

        </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

**final working rss feed:**

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}" status="open|publish"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

        <channel>

        <title><![CDATA[Blog]]></title>
        <link>{channel_url}</link>
        <description>{channel_description}</description>
        <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
        <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
        <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
        <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
        <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|pagination" status="open|publish"}
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[{title}]]></title>
            <link>{page_url}</link>
            <guid>{page_url}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[{article_body}]]></description>
            <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}]]></dc:subject>
            <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
        </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

        </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied and pasted your template code into a new template in a site in my dev environment. The only value I changed was the `master_channel_name` value to match one of my channels.

I see all entries being output.

You mention:

> adding status="publish" since that's the status that a blog post has to be to display.

I would closely examine your custom Status values, or stick with open|closed to try to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: @mark-j-reeves Thank you! this got me a bit further.. I changed one of the statuses on a post to "open" and the post is displaying in the rss.. is there anything special that i have to do to get the "publish" status to display in the rss?

Comment: You'll need to add `status="open|publish"` to your `exp:channel:entries` tag. By default, that tag will only assume `open`.

Comment: I found something strange.. if I add `status="open|publish" still nothing displays, but if i switch 1 post to the status of `open` they display.. is there any explanation why that happens so i can understand for the future?

Comment: Thats the right syntax (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#status). Are you sure you're writing "publish" the exact same way you've defined it in your custom statuses?

Comment: I got it working with all posts on `publish` instead of 1 post being on open now :) i had to add `status="open|publish" to the `exp:channel:entries` and `exp:rss:feed` :) thanks for the help!